# TypeScript's control flow analysis with strictNullChecks does not narrow down union types

Tags: typescript

I have the following code from the book https://hamednourhani.gitbooks.io/typescript-book/

```
interface Square {
    kind: "square";
    size: number;
}

interface Rectangle {
    kind: "rectangle";
    width: number;
    height: number;
}

interface Circle {
    kind: "circle";
    radius: number;
}

type Shape = Square | Rectangle | Circle;

//Type of function: function area1(s: Square | Rectangle | Circle): number | undefined
function area1(s: Shape) {
    if (s.kind === "square") {
        return s.size * s.size;
    }
    else if (s.kind === "rectangle") {
        return s.width * s.height;
    }
    else if (s.kind === "circle") {
        return Math.PI * s.radius * s.radius;
    }
    else {
        //Type 'Square | Rectangle' is not assignable to type 'never'.
        const _exhaustiveCheck: never = s;
    }
}

//Function lacks ending return statement and return type does not include 'undefined'.
function area2(s: Shape): number {
    switch (s.kind) {
        case "square": return s.size * s.size;
        case "rectangle": return s.width * s.height;
        case "circle": return Math.PI * s.radius * s.radius;
        default: const _exhaustiveCheck: never = s; //Type of s is 'never'
    }
}
```

Questions (--strictNullChecks):

- why does in 2 functions `s` in expression `_exhaustiveCheck: never = s`
  have different types? I expected `s` to be `never` in both cases.
- why `area2` function wants to have return type `number | undefined`? It seems to me undefined can never happen here. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have the following code from the book https://hamednourhani.gitbooks.io/typescript-book/

That book URL is wrong. The original one is : http://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/ . Since its free and open source means people are free to create duplicates. Doesn't bother me much (seem unintentional and I'm assuming non malicious) but thought I'd mention the up to date version link. Now on to your questions

> why does in 2 functions s in expression _exhaustiveCheck: never = s have different types? I expected s to be never in both cases.

The code you posted is also not the code in the book's relevant section https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/discriminated-unions.html Assuming you modified it :)

Thats fine. When I run your sample though I get `never` for both versions. And as you can see `s` is of type `never` in both cases and there is no error. The comment is wrong:

[image]

> why area2 function wants to have return type number | undefined? It seems to me undefined can never happen here. Am I wrong?

Just to be clear *both* functions want to have type `number | undefined`. That is simply because TypeScript has figured out that there is code that is executing in the some region but not returning. It didn't figure out that the region is `never` region. However you can easily help it but simply returning the `never`. Fixed code:

```
interface Square {
    kind: "square";
    size: number;
}

interface Rectangle {
    kind: "rectangle";
    width: number;
    height: number;
}

interface Circle {
    kind: "circle";
    radius: number;
}

type Shape = Square | Rectangle | Circle;

// Type of function: function area1(s: Square | Rectangle | Circle): number
function area1(s: Shape) {
    if (s.kind === "square") {
        return s.size * s.size;
    }
    else if (s.kind === "rectangle") {
        return s.width * s.height;
    }
    else if (s.kind === "circle") {
        return Math.PI * s.radius * s.radius;
    }
    else {
      // Type of s is never
      const _exhaustiveCheck: never = s;
      return _exhaustiveCheck;
    }
}

// No Error 
function area2(s: Shape): number {
    switch (s.kind) {
        case "square": return s.size * s.size;
        case "rectangle": return s.width * s.height;
        case "circle": return Math.PI * s.radius * s.radius;
        default:
          const _exhaustiveCheck: never = s; // Type of s is 'never'
          return _exhaustiveCheck;
    }
}
```

PS: I've updated the book with `strictNullChecks` as well : https://github.com/basarat/typescript-book/blob/master/docs/types/discriminated-unions.md#strictnullchecks

Comment: Thank you very much for being kind and answering this as it turned out cumbersome question. I probably messed something up and got this problem of `s` being `Square | Rectangle` in the final block. Sorry for that, next time I will post a question after having some rest and fresh look at the problem. I will also read YOUR version of the book, did not notice it was the wrong version :-)